# redirect to the page according to the url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

hello all i need to redirect the users to specific pages when some perticular link is clicked like
if clicked on : `www.xyz.com/user.php?user=abhi` to this url `www.xyz.com/user/abhi`
and if clicked on `www.xyz.com/dash.php?person=niki` to this `www.xyz.com/dash/niki` and so on

i know this can be done by .htaccess but i have a little problem i dont know how to write htaccess for multiple links i know about single link
like

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?brand=([^\s&]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page.php?brand=$1 [L,QSA]
```

this code directs the user from `page.php?brand=abc` to `domain.com/abc`

i would be highly thankfull if you can tell me how to write htaccess for multiple redirects about 6 redirects are needed and also tell me is this ok to redirect the users by htaccess

Comment: *tell me is this ok to redirect the users by htaccess* when i understand your example the answer is **No** google for the main usage of htaccess ..

Comment: Google is a search engine, Not well known but you should give it a try!

Comment: it is banned here in india

Comment: Really? That's insane! everywhere in India?

Comment: @Notflip: No, that's an enormous exaggeration. Wikipedia's page on the subject is actually pretty good: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_India

Comment: I did not know! That's insane! sorry for the offtopic